# Is it possible using the Java AWS API to update a Route53 record?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I have a hosted domain on AWS Route53. Under that domain I have an 'A' record for a subdomain.

I would like to be able to update the IP address of the 'A' record using the Java API. However, when looking at the `setAction` method of the `com.amazonaws.services.route53.model.Change` class, it only accepts the `CREATE` or `DELETE` values. This seems to match the allowed values in the XML message that the Java API sends behind the scenes.

Is there any way to just update the IP address, or do I have to delete the original record and then create it again?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way is to use DELETE / CREATE sequence as mentioned [here](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/RRSchanges.html).

> Creating a Change Batch Request
>
> To create a change batch request, use the ChangeResourceRecordSets
>   action ChangeBatch element. You use CREATE and DELETE actions within
>   the ChangeBatch element for each record that you want to update. If
>   you are only creating records, then you will only use CREATE actions.

Comment: Any idea if it would at least be possible to delete "any existing" resourceRecordSet, rather than specifying both name and AliasTarget (in case of an alias)? I want to "set resource" overwriting any there, and don't want to have to first find one and delete it if it's there... though maybe I'll have to (sorry for verbosity of my comment).

Answer (score 4):

It worked for me using this piece of code:

```
ResourceRecord record = new ResourceRecord(loadBalancer);
List<ResourceRecord> records = new ArrayList<ResourceRecord>();
records.add(record);
ResourceRecordSet recordsSet = new ResourceRecordSet();
recordsSet.setResourceRecords(records);
recordsSet.setType(RRType.CNAME);
recordsSet.setTTL(900L);
recordsSet.setName(subdomain + ".");
Change change = new Change(ChangeAction.CREATE, recordsSet);
List<Change> changes = new ArrayList<Change>();
changes.add(change);
ChangeBatch batch = new ChangeBatch(changes);
ChangeResourceRecordSetsRequest request = new ChangeResourceRecordSetsRequest();
request.setChangeBatch(batch);
request.setHostedZoneId(hostedZoneId);
ChangeResourceRecordSetsResult result = getRoute53Client().changeResourceRecordSets(request);
System.out.println(result);
```

Just replace the variables I used with proper data. (subdomain, loadBalancer and hostedZoneId). The method getRoute53Client() returns an instance of the AmazonRoute53Client class from the AWS API.

Answer (score 4):

```
        ResourceRecord rr = new ResourceRecord(IPAdress); // IPAddress will be String variable that has IP value
        List<ResourceRecord> rrList = new ArrayList<ResourceRecord>();
        rrList.add(rr);

        // Create a ResourceRecordSet
        ResourceRecordSet resourceRecordSet = new ResourceRecordSet();
        resourceRecordSet.setName(domainName); //domainName is String value of your domain
        resourceRecordSet.setType(RRType.A); //type of ResourceRecordSet
        resourceRecordSet.setTTL(new Long(300));
        resourceRecordSet.setWeight(new Long(0));
        resourceRecordSet.setResourceRecords(rrList);

        // Create a change
        Change change = new Change(ChangeAction.CREATE, resourceRecordSet);
        List<Change> changesList = new ArrayList<Change>();
        changesList.add(change);

        // Create a change batch
        ChangeBatch changeBatch = new ChangeBatch(changesList);

        // Create ChangeResourceRecordSetRequest.
        ChangeResourceRecordSetsRequest request = new ChangeResourceRecordSetsRequest(hostedZoneID, changeBatch); //hostedZoneId is variable that is the id of HostedZone

        // Send the request and get the response.
        ChangeResourceRecordSetsResult result = amazonRoute53Client.changeResourceRecordSets(request);

        // Print the result
        System.out.println(result.getChangeInfo());
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please include a text explanation to make your answer clearer and higher quality for the community. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

hostedzoneId = "***hosted zone id from the route53***"
aliasTargetHostedzoneId = "***zone id of the connected resource such as loadbalancer, cloudfront etc..***"

```
Route53Client route53Client = Route53Client.builder()
            .credentialsProvider(StaticCredentialsProvider.create(awsCreds))
            .region(Region.AWS_GLOBAL)
            .build();


    AliasTarget aliasTarget = AliasTarget.builder()
            .dnsName(loadBalancerDomain)
            .evaluateTargetHealth(false)
            .hostedZoneId(aliasTargetHostedzoneId)
            .build();

    // Create a ResourceRecordSet
    ResourceRecordSet resourceRecordSet = ResourceRecordSet.builder()
            .name(fullDomainName+".")
            .type(RRType.A)
            .aliasTarget(aliasTarget)
            .build();


    // Create a change
    Change change = Change.builder()
            .action(ChangeAction.CREATE)
            .resourceRecordSet(resourceRecordSet)
            .build();

    List<Change> changesList = new ArrayList<Change>();
    changesList.add(change);

    // Create a change batch
    ChangeBatch changeBatch = ChangeBatch.builder()
            .changes(changesList)
            .build();

    // Create ChangeResourceRecordSetRequest.
    ChangeResourceRecordSetsRequest request = ChangeResourceRecordSetsRequest.builder()
            .hostedZoneId(hostedzoneId)
            .changeBatch(changeBatch)
            .build();

    // Send the request and get the response.
    ChangeResourceRecordSetsResponse result = route53Client.changeResourceRecordSets(request);
```